# Append arguments to Javascript functions, rather than prepend (Function.prototype.bind)

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Javascript (Node.js context), I use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) regularly: `bind` allows for changing invocation context and optionally supplying additional **prepended** arguments.

Are there any recommendations for **appending** arguments? On a couple occasions I have encountered the need to append rather than prepend in Node.js so I can adhere to its function signature pattern.

Now for a semi-practical and simplified example; I'm using the [async module's `eachSeries` method](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries).

First, an implementation that wraps the callback (working, but long way):

```
function func(something,callback) {
    async.eachSeries(
        [1,2,3],
        function iterator(item,asyncCallback) {
            // do stuff
            asyncCallback(err||null);
        },
        function finished(err) {
            // `callback` expects 2 arguments
            // `err` should always be the first arg, null or otherwise
            // `something` (unrelated to the async series) should be maintained
            callback(err,something);
        }
    );
};
```

And now something a bit shorter:

```
function func(something,callback) {
    async.eachSeries(
        [1,2,3],
        function iterator(item,asyncCallback) {
            // do stuff
            asyncCallback(err||null);
        },
        callback.bindAppend(this,something)
        // pseudo-equiv: `callback.bind(this,err,something);`
    );
};
```

In the second example, the `err` is carried from `eachSeries`'s `asyncCallback` callback, while `something` is provided by other means. To clarify, I'm looking to replace `bindAppend` from the "shorter" example that would have the functional equivalent of `function finished` in the "longer" example.

Perhaps my design is flawed and needs to be reworked or this is just another case of premature optimization. However, the feature I seek could provide the following benefits:

1. simplified code in regards to legibility IMO
2. decreased and simplified stack depth

One answer would be to roll my own from a forked Function.prototype.bind polyfill. However,  I'm looking for either a native implementation that I'm not seeing, a close-to-native work-around, or a utility module that has the hard work already done (optimization, testing, etc.).  *FYI, any solution other than the former would actually worsen feature benefit #2.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming i understood the question,my first shot at it with tests :

```
Function.prototype.bindAppend = function(context) {
    var func = this;
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments).slice(1);
    return function() {
        return func.apply(context, [].slice.call(arguments).concat(args));
    }
}
```

---

Test:

```
Function.prototype.bindAppend = function(context) {
    var func = this;
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments).slice(1);
    return function() {
        return func.apply(context, [].slice.call(arguments).concat(args));
    }
}

describe('bindAppend', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        this.obj = {
            value: "a",
            func: function() {
                return this.value + [].slice.call(arguments).join('');
            }
        }
    });

    it('should work  properly', function() {
        expect(this.obj.func.bindAppend(this.obj, "c")("b")).toEqual("abc");
    });
    it('should work  properly', function() {
        expect(this.obj.func.bindAppend(this.obj, "c", "d")("b")).toEqual("abcd");
    });
    it('should work  properly', function() {
        expect(this.obj.func.bindAppend(this.obj, "d")("b", "c")).toEqual("abcd");
    });
})
```

Working version: https://mparaiso.github.io/playground/#/gist/hivsHLuAuV

Comment: this is along the lines of what I was thinking, but was just hoping there was an internal/native solution I was missing. I think this is about as elegant as we're gunna get.

Comment: native no,but you could submit a request to TC39 to get something like this in the spec.

Comment: At first, I was confused with [].slice.call(arguments). But all it does is create a new array. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects).

Answer (score 2):

There are no native solutions. But I can propose you something like this:

```
Function.prototype.bindAppend = function (context) {
  var bindArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  var func = this;
  return function() {
    var funcArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var args = bindArgs.map(function(arg) {
      if (arg === undefined) return funcArgs.shift();
      return arg;
    }).concat(funcArgs);
    func.apply(context, args);
  }
}
```

And usage:

```
function func(something,callback) {
    async.eachSeries(
        [1,2,3],
        function iterator(item,asyncCallback) {
            // do stuff
            asyncCallback(err||null);
        },
        callback.bindAppend(this, undefined, something)
        // pseudo-equiv: `callback.bind(this,err,something);`
    );
};
```

Other example:

```
function a() {console.log.apply(console, arguments)};
var b = a.bindAppend(null, 1, undefined, 3, undefined, 5);
b(2,4,6,7); //1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Comment: This is pretty clever: on the implementation side it allows for maintaining a formal/defined function signature. The only caution I have is with shifting undefined args (e.g. `arg === undefined && funcArgs.shift()`); in some cases `undefined` is a legitimate argument in the case when they're optional or can be handled gracefully - I don't see how your method would allow for this scenario.

Comment: You can use very specific string marker to avoid this collision ```if (arg === "__bind_marker__")...```.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of maintainability, I would not add a method to `Function` to achieve this. The other answers to the question here contain two implementation of `Function.prototype.bindAppend` that are incompatible with each other. So imagine creating your own `bindAppend` and then having to use your application with a body of code whose author decided to do the same thing but uses a implementation incompatible with yours.

Polyfills *are* fine insofar as they aim to fill in a missing function according to a specific standard. A polyfill for `Function.prototype.bind`, for instance, is not free to deviate from ECMA-262, 5th edition. If it does deviate, then it is arguably "buggy" and should be replaced with an implementation that does not deviate from the standard. When one implements methods that are not defined by a standard there's no such constraint.

The following benchmarking suite shows the difference between various ways of attaining the result in the question.

```
var async = require("async");
var Benchmark = require("benchmark");
var suite = new Benchmark.Suite();

function dump (err, something) {
    console.log(arguments);
    console.log(err, something);
}

function addToSuite(name, makeFinished) {
    function func(something, callback) {
        async.eachSeries([1,2,3],
                         function iterator(item, asyncCallback) {
                             var err;
                             // do stuff
                             asyncCallback(err || null);
                         },
                         makeFinished(this, something, callback)
                        );
    }

    console.log(name, "dump");
    func("foo", dump);
    console.log("");

    suite.add(name, function () {
        func("foo", function (err, something) {});
    });
}

// Taken from mpm's http://stackoverflow.com/a/23670553/1906307
Function.prototype.bindAppend = function(context) {
    var func = this;
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments).slice(1);
    return function() {
        return func.apply(context, [].slice.call(arguments).concat(args));
    };
};

addToSuite("anonymous function", function (context, something, callback) {
    return function finished(err) {
        callback(err, something);
    };
});

addToSuite("mpm's bindAppend", function (context, something, callback) {
    return callback.bindAppend(context, something);
});

addToSuite("addErr, only one parameter", function (context, something,
                                                   callback) {
    function addErr(f, something) {
        return function (err) {
            return f(err, something);
        };
    }

    return addErr(callback, something);
});

addToSuite("addErr, multi param", function (context, something, callback) {
    function addErr(f, one, two, three, four, five, six) {
        return function (err) {
            return f(err, one, two, three, four, five, six);
        };
    }

    return addErr(callback, something);
});

addToSuite("addErr, switch", function (context, something, callback) {
    function addErr(f, one, two, three, four, five, six) {
        var args = arguments;
        return function (err) {
            switch(args.length) {
            case 1: return f(err);
            case 2: return f(err, one);
            case 3: return f(err, one, two);
            case 4: return f(err, one, two, three);
            case 5: return f(err, one, two, three, four);
            case 6: return f(err, one, two, three, four, five);
            case 6: return f(err, one, two, three, four, five, six);
            default: throw Error("unsupported number of args");
            }
        };
    }
    return addErr(callback, something);
});

suite
    .on('cycle', function(event) {
        console.log(String(event.target));
    })
    .on('complete', function() {
        console.log('The fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').pluck('name'));
    })
    .run();
```

Output:

```
anonymous function dump
{ '0': undefined, '1': 'foo' }
undefined 'foo'

mpm's bindAppend dump
{ '0': 'foo' }
foo undefined

addErr, only one parameter dump
{ '0': undefined, '1': 'foo' }
undefined 'foo'

addErr, multi param dump
{ '0': undefined,
  '1': 'foo',
  '2': undefined,
  '3': undefined,
  '4': undefined,
  '5': undefined,
  '6': undefined }
undefined 'foo'

addErr, switch dump
{ '0': undefined, '1': 'foo' }
undefined 'foo'

anonymous function x 4,137,843 ops/sec ±3.18% (93 runs sampled)
mpm's bindAppend x 663,044 ops/sec ±1.42% (97 runs sampled)
addErr, only one parameter x 3,944,633 ops/sec ±1.89% (91 runs sampled)
addErr, multi param x 3,209,292 ops/sec ±2.57% (84 runs sampled)
addErr, switch x 3,087,979 ops/sec ±2.00% (91 runs sampled)
The fastest is anonymous function
```

Notes:

- The `dump` calls dump to screen what it is the final callback gets when there is no error whatsoever.
- When there is no error, mpm's `bindAppend` implementation will call `callback` with only one parameter that has the value `"foo"`. This is a very different behavior from the original `function finished(err) { callback(err,something);}` callback it is meant to replace.
- Everything is faster than mpm's `bindAppend`.
- I would not use the `addErr, multi param` implementation. I put it there to check how that approach would perform.
- The `addErr` functions are faster than `bindAppend`, at the cost of flexibility. They add only one parameter to the callback.

At the end of the day, I'd most likely use the `addErr, switch` implementation with a large enough number of cases to handle the needs of my code. If I needed something which would have absolute flexibility, for some limited cases, I'd use something similar to `bindAppend` but not as a method on `Function`.

Comment: +1, informative. perf-wise, it looks like I should stick with the lambda (finished wrapper) rather than trying to use `Function.prototype.bindAppend`. I'll ponder your `addErr` solutions a bit more, but right now they seem too solution-specific; I'm searching for something general and natural.

Comment: Reading your comment makes me realize I called the first case "anonymous function" when in fact it is not anonymous. I typically use anonymous functions for these.

Answer (score 1):

lodash _.partial allows you to append arguments..

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partial

```
function test(a, b, c) {
    return a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c;
}

test.bind(null, 1)(2, 3); // 1 2 3

_.partial(test, _, _, 1)(2, 3); // 2 3 1
```

Comment: `_.partialRight` does the same thing w/o the placeholders; placeholders, as with `_.partial` to _append_, assume your function signature is known, so it is not appropriate for all cases.